# Feed file path into Pandas DF for PyTest as command line parameter

Tags: python, pandas, csv, command-line, pytest

so I am trying to find a way to parameterize tests a bit better for data validation. I have basic tests I’ve created in PyTest that involve me reading a .csv file and loading it into a Pandas DF. From there I’m doing simple checks like checking for duplicates, verifying data types and whatnot. All of that works just fine.

However I want to be able to share the script with colleagues and allow for them to simply execute from the command line by feeding the file name into the test. I know that PyTest allows for parameterization but everything I’ve found thus far is for simple text and number inputs, haven’t seen anything helpful for file inputs.

Anyone had experience with this?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm not understanding what you're trying to do, but if you're trying to check that some tabular data is properly sanitized, that's not what pytest is for.  Pytest is for writing unit tests, and in that context it doesn't really make sense to share scripts with colleagues who would provide their own input files.

I think what you want is a data validation library, e.g. [pandera](https://pandera.readthedocs.io/en/stable/index.html#).  This would allow you to handle any command-line arguments yourself, and would also probably simplify the actual data validation steps.